# C# WPF DataTable bound to GridView (more precisely Telerik's RadGridView)

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datatable, telerik

I have a little problem. I have a MySQL table schema that changes regularly (i.e. the columns and their types). I programmed my ORM to store it in the form of a DataTable instead of a fixed serializable type as a result of this requirement.

I am now interested in showing this table in a window. Precisely, it will be bound to a GridView object (the RadGridView type in Telerik library. I bound the table using the following code:

```
DataTable dt = GetMyTable();
radGridView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

This works fine. However, if I am to update this table with the following code, then the process is excruciatingly slow:

```
dt.BeginLoadData();
for (object[] new_row in new_rows) {
    dt.Rows.Add(new_row);
}
dt.EndLoadData();
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

I understand that DataTable dumps out a whole slew of events on update, but they should be turned off by the BeginLoadData() call - in theory at least.

I've also tried using an adaptor called BindingSource with steps documented in this [page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55730/Achieve-performance-while-updating-a-datatable-bou)

This did speed things up a bit but still not efficient enough.

My objective here is to do batch loading with my DataTable where whenever a new batch of rows is added to it from a thread, it the GridView will also update to show the new rows. And obviously, I want to do this as efficiently as possible.

Any inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the code being run on the UI thread or a worker thread? The point of the BeginLoadData/EndLoadData pattern is to decouple the UI thread from a IEnumerable whilst you update the data from another thread (which would normally cause an exception), thus keep the UI thread free to update the UI.

Comment: PS What do you mean by efficient? If you mean more responsive, typically that would make the code LESS efficient from a CPU point of view. If you do mean using less time to do the UI update, I am afraid this is likely the fastest it can get without virtual rows.

Comment: The batch loading is done on a worker thread. I want the process to be both fast and the GUI not to freeze. I am all for UI virtualization if that solves the issue.

Comment: It should help. The likely reason for the UI to "freeze" is that the RadGridView is busy creating RadGridViewRowInfo foreach new element. Since they are UI elements, they need to be done on the UI thread. UI virtualization defers the creation of the GridViewRowInfo until the user actually scrolls down to the new rows. Of course then if you ever enumerate the GridViewRowInfo you would not get every one for each data element.

Comment: Is there any guide I can read about this? AFAIK, Telerik's grid already has virtualization settings on by default.

Comment: Just took a look at the decompiler and the docs. By default WPF its on and by default it is off on WinForms.